# RGBDSLAM V2 catkin_make error

Tags: ros, rgbdslamv2, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the RGBDSLAM V2 using the steps that are shown [here](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) under the "Installation From Scratch" but failed and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
Base path: /home/ceastech/rgbdslam
Source space: /home/ceastech/rgbdslam/src
Build space: /home/ceastech/rgbdslam/build
Devel space: /home/ceastech/rgbdslam/devel
Install space: /home/ceastech/rgbdslam/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ceastech/rgbdslam/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ceastech/rgbdslam/build"
####
[ 14%] Built target siftgpu_proj
[ 23%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_lisp
[ 37%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
[ 37%] [ 37%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
Built target rgbdslam_gencpp
[ 39%] [ 41%] [ 42%] [ 44%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_graph_manager.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/qtros.o
Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o
/tmp/ccJWleRv.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccJWleRv.s:6501: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccJWleRv.s:7191: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_graph_manager.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/tmp/ccmwwdFs.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccmwwdFs.s:6316: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccmwwdFs.s:7006: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.o] Error 1
/tmp/ccemUxBv.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccemUxBv.s:9379: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/ccemUxBv.s:10069: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o] Error 1
/tmp/cci4xF2j.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cci4xF2j.s:211470: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
/tmp/cci4xF2j.s:212160: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss (%ecx),%xmm0,%xmm1'
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190688/rgbdslam-v2-catkin_make-error/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone that may run into this in the future:

In `catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeLists.txt` add `-march=native -mno-avx` to  `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` :

`SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-ggdb -O3 -fPIC -std=c++0x -march=native -mno-avx")`

I am running 12.04LTS with Hydro and Haswell chipset.

---

Originally posted by [nitekrawler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20470/nitekrawler/) with karma: 93 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2014-11-21**:
Interesting, as far as I know, catkin automatically uses -march=native, which I understand to be "autodetection" of cpu flags. So probably this autodetection fails here.

**Comment by [vinot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4639/vinot/) on 2014-12-06**:
yes, it works

thank you